# Java: removing multiple occurrences of unprintable characters from group

Tags: java, regex, string, string-formatting

In out application we need to compare and manipulate functions code like the following:

```
function void disableTestOnDevice(SampleBuilder sample,String devices,String[] devTestCode) {\r\n\t\t   if(devices == null)\r\n\t\t\t   return;\r\n\t       if(sample.getListTransc() != null && sample.getListTransc().size() > 0){\t\r\n\t\t\t\tfor(int i = sample.getListTransc().size()-1; i >= 0; i--){\r\n\t\t\t\t\tViewWorklistBuilder j = (ViewWorklistBuilder)sample.getListTransc().get(i);\r\n\t\t\t\t\tif(j.getDeviceId() == null || j.getDeviceTestCode() == null || j.getDeviceSpecimenCode() == null){\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tcontinue;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t\t\tif(j.getDeviceId().equals(devices)){\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif(devTestCode != null){\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tfor(int k = 0;  k < devTestCode.length; k++){\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tif(j.getDeviceTestCode().equals(devTestCode[k])){\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tj.setEnabled(0);\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tbreak;\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t}\r\n\t       }\r\n\t\r\n
```

Sometimes it happens that some extra `\t`, `\r` or `\n` is added, I don't know why.
So, before comparing two functions (two String objects) I would like to remove multiple occurrences of unprintable characters from each group.
For example, a group like 
`\r\n\t\r\n` should become `\t\r\n`

Or maybe, something like

```
if(devices == null)\r\n\t\t\t   return;\r\n\t\t
for(int i = sample.getListTransc().size()-1; i >= 0; i--){\t\r\n\t\t\t\tSystem.out.println(i);\t\r\n\t\t\t\}
```

should become

```
if(devices == null)\r\n\t   return;\r\n\t
for(int i = sample.getListTransc().size()-1; i >= 0; i--){\t\r\nSystem.out.println(i);\t\r\n}
```

Or maybe, my problem could be a little more insidious.
I mean that it may be necessary that any group of unprintable characters matching `\r\n\t` should become `\n\t`

Comment: Ehm, I have an example...a very long example, the code I wrote at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Are you looking for regular expressions? [Regular Expressions (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

Comment: So in you string, we can see `\r\n\t`, in memory is `\\r\\n\\t` I'm wrong ?

Comment: No, I mean that String is stored in DB with `\r\n\t` while from front end, each of that group arrives as `\n\t`... it seems that `\r` is added before `\n\t`. SO I would like to make them equal before comparing them

Comment: In your "should become", you don't want to transform `\r\n\t\t\t` in `\r\n\t` but in `\n\t`, correct ?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to transform `\r\n\t\t\t` in `\n\t\t\t`. So each time there is a group (or a subgroup) matching `\r\n\t` it should become `\n\t`. Both it's a group itself or part of a bigger group

Comment: The problem is only to replace `\r\n` by `\n` ? Sorry for the question but is not very clear, because in not that you write in your "something like... should become"

Comment: Yes, I think that, in the end, the problem is reduced to replace \r\n by \n...Excuse me for my confusion, I've never used regex and moreover I'm having difficulties in understanding why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is to compare the change with another string, a possible solution is to remove `\r`, `\n` and `\t` in both and compare it.

```
String s = "function void disableTestOnDevice(SampleBuilder sample,String devices,String[] devTestCode) {\r\n\t\t if(devices == null)\r\n\t\t\t return;\r\n\t";
String s1 = "function void disableTestOnDevice(SampleBuilder sample,String devices,String[] devTestCode) {\n\t\t if(devices == null)\n\t\t\t return;\n\t";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\r|\\n|\\t", ""));
// false
System.out.println(s.equals(s1));
// true
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\r|\\n|\\t", "").equals(s1.replaceAll("\\r|\\n|\\t", "")));
```